# Weird stretching in smooth shading

Tags: rendering, topology, bevel

I'm new to Blender, so I have questions about my topology. While editing the beveled edges, I realized there is stretching in the adjacent faces. The shade looks a bit weird as you can see on the second screen. I have auto smooth normals checked as well. I wonder if the problem is my topology, or something else? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your topology is mostly very good, but I think that your shading problem is that the area I marked with the crude blue box is a 5-pole.

I would use the knife tool to add the edge I crudely drew in orange, and then I would select the two diagonals leading to the pole and dissolve them.

You could fix a similar problem with the next diagonals down, if the shading issue bothers you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I did what you said and solved the issue!